# ListView в simple_list_item_multiple_choice вместо галочки поставить крестик

Tags: android, listview

Как в ListView в multipleChoice свойтсве вместо галочку изменить на крестик. Пользуюсь simple_list_item_multiple_choice, но там только галочка.

Answer (score 1):

Привет. Тебе необходимо создать кастомный CheckBox

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
</selector>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    android:text="Custom CheckBox" />
```